# Basic nasm shellcode crashes

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls, ld

I'm learning assembly, so I'm working on shellcode. I wrote a simple "hello world" program in nasm, but it crashes when run.

```
; write.asm
[SECTION .text]

global _start

_start:
    jmp short message;

write:          ; takes two arguments pushed onto stack -> text, textlen
    pop edx     ; pop length into edx
    pop ecx     ; pop ptr to text into ecx
    pushad
    mov al, 4
    mov bl, 1
    int 80h    ; syscall
    popad
    ret

exit:           ; push exit_code onto stack
    mov al, 1
    pop ebx     ; pop exit_code into ebx
    int 80h

main:
    pop eax     ; pop ptr to message into eax
    push 7      ; length of string
    push eax    ; push ptr to message
    call write
    xor ebx, ebx; zero out ebx
    push ebx
    call exit
message:
    call main
    db 'Hello!', 10
```

I compile it with:

```
nasm -f elf write.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o write write.o
```

and get this:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried debugging it with gdb, but it didn't help.

Comment: isnt the string Hello! should end with 0? since it is a string?

Comment: @rcd Since this is a call to write and I have to supply the length of the string, no, it doesn't need to be null-terminated.

Comment: What does running it in a debugger show? Where do you think the `ret` instruction will return since you popped it off the stack at the beginning of `write`? Maybe you forgot that with a `call` that the return address is pushed on the stack? I suspect that since you popped the return address plus the first argument that your code attempted to return to memory address 7 which would have been at the top of the stack when your call to `write` returns.

Comment: in pop edx, i think you have popped the return adddress, from the call? instead of the length? did you check?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow, you are totally right. I modified the write routine to pop the return address into esi and then push that onto the stack after the popad instruction. Now it doesn't crash, but just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You got both of those right. I fixed that by zeroing out the registers and switching edx and ecx. It now works when compiled into an elf binary. However, when compiled into a binary blob, e.i. shellcode, it crashes. (I wrote a short program to read it from the file and pass execution to it)

Comment: @Fluffy i think you should trace the esp if it points to the values you expected. i think you disregard the way the call manipulates the stack. before using pop or push inspect in your debugger if it really points to the correct variable. i suspect it crashes because the execution returns to an invalid address.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to show to you, how you could find your problem by using gdb:

1. Start gdb and load your program: `>> gdb write`
2. Set breakpoint directly at start: `(gdb) b _start`.You could just let the program run until segfault, but if the stack is messed up, the chances are high you will not see anything.
3. Set up the display to show 5 top values on the stack automatically after every step:  `(gdb) display/x {unsigned int[5]}$sp`
4. To see the next executed line: `(gdb) display/i $pc`
5. Now run: `(gdb) run`

Debugger hits the  breakpoint and you see the stack set up by the system:

```
1: /x {unsigned int[5]}$sp = {0x1, 0xffffd284, 0x0, 0xffffd29d, 0xffffd2b2}
```

Everything Ok so far, the program was started with one argument (`0x1` on the top) - the path to the program (you can see it by `(gdb) print (char[10])*(0xffffd284)`).

6. make a step `(gdb) si`, now we jumped to the `message` symbol.

With `(gdb) disas` one can see more of the code:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function message:
=> 0x08048083 <+0>: call   0x8048072 <main>
   0x08048088 <+5>: dec    %eax
   0x08048089 <+6>: gs
   0x0804808a <+7>: insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   0x0804808b <+8>: insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   0x0804808c <+9>: outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
   0x0804808d <+10>:    and    %ecx,(%edx)
End of assembler dump.
```

As you can see, your "Hello"-string is interpreted as operations beginning at `0x08048088`

7. make another step: `(gdb) si`, going into the function `main`.

Now take a look at the stack:

```
 1: /x {unsigned int[5]}$sp = {0x8048088, 0x1, 0xffffd283, 0x0, 0xffffd29c}
```

The `call`-instruction pushed the return address on the stack - `0x08048088` - the address of your string. Nice trick, let's hope `main` will never return...

8. let's fast forward to the call of `write`: `(gdb) si 3` and go inside `(gdb) si`.

Let's look at the stack, as expected, `call` added the return address to the stack:

```
1: /x {unsigned int[5]}$sp = {0x804807b, 0x8048088, 0x7, 0x1, 0xffffd283}
```

9. Your program expects the pointer to the string and the length to be on top, but this is not the case.
10. Lets fast forward to the return of the function `write`: `(gdb) si 7`.

Take a look at the stack:

```
1: /x {unsigned int[5]}$sp = {0x7, 0x1, 0xffffd283, 0x0, 0xffffd29c}
```

the next operation - `ret` will pop `0x7` from the stack and try to assume the execution at the address `0x7` which results in a segfault (as rcd suspected).

So your problem is that your functions corrupt the stack. Normally, the function setting up the stack for a call is also responsible for cleaning it up afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. However, compiling it into a binary and running it doesn't crash after fixing some of the stuff presented by the commenters of the main post. It doesn't work as shell code, but I think that might be an issue with the way I'm running it as shell code.

Comment: @Fluffy it is hard to tell, what your problem could be - but I hope you can use debugger to find the problem. It would take more time than asking somebody - but in the long run it will pay off.